# How to conditionally include a file in PHP

Tags: php

I have made a website and it works fine..
But now I want to be able to have non computer minded people be able to change if one line shows up or not..
I was going to achive this by having  a line of php include

```
<?php include 'on.php'; ?>
```

and they name the file "on" to have it display the text in the php file this works fine..
But then when the name it off.. it displays a error (obviously because it cant find anything) but i would like to keep my set up the same but remove the error meassage or maybe have a if statement saying that if it cant find anything do nothing.

How would/should i go about this?

Comment: create a db table, and an interface, so they can edit that line in a form, giving them access to a php file seems crazy dangerous.

Comment: and if they are "*non computer minded*" how are they creating a PHP file, or is that just the extension but it's text or HTML?

Comment: They are not creating anything i have it all and all they have to do is rename a file

Comment: non computer minded person adding `exec('rm -r');` and if they rename it to an existing file name? you want a CMS or at lest something a little smarter than this approach

Comment: Than how should i go about it?

Comment: form, db, checkbox, not enough information to say much more

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$filename = 'on.php'; // or whatever

if (is_readable($filename)) {
    include $filename;
}
```

Comment: @Lachlan Then I simply don't understand your question

Comment: Ok i want it to show some text when a file is labeled on.php and when its labeled off.php i dont want it to do anything.. How do i go about this?

Comment: Just as @Phil has shown.  Maybe you haven't provided enough or accurate info?

Comment: @Lachlan That's what my answer does. If there is no `on.php`, it will not be included